# In R, is there any native function to get a row or column of a matrix, depending on the parameter?

Tags: r

I am currently using this implementation:

```
getVal = function(i, x, margin) {
    rst = ifelse(margin==1, x[i, ], x[, i])
}
```

i.e. return the i-th row OR column of x, depending on the value of margin.

=== update ===

Just realized my usage of `ifelse(x,y,z)` statement here is wrong, as it returns a value the same length as its first argument. My implementation of `getVal` should have:

```
...
rst = if (margin == 1) x[i, ] else x[, i]
...
```

Comment: are you doing more things with this column or row?

Comment: what type of object is x? a matrix versus a data.frame will be different answers.

Comment: @Maiasaura, I may use the output of getVal, but I am assuming here 'apply' is not an option.

Comment: are you wanting to consider more than 2 dimensions?

Comment: @Justin, is there any native generic function accepting either (or both) matrix or data.frame?

Comment: @james I was considering 2-D matrix, but supporting for high-D array is appealing too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`abind::asub()` does something very much like what you're trying to do (and also generalizes nicely to higher-dimensional arrays). Its `idx` and `dims` arguments correspond, respectively, to your `i` and  `margin` arguments.

```
library(abind)

(m <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    3    6

asub(x = m, idx = 2, dims = 1)   # Extract 2nd row
# [1] 2 5

asub(x = m, idx = 2, dims = 2)   # Extract 2nd column
# [1] 4 5 6
```